# Angular ng-include strange behavior - causing URL address change

Tags: angularjs

I've noticed a strange behavior of ng-include -- it is causing a strange side effect on the browser in some cases.

Here is a page, that contains a simple twitter bootstrap tab pane

```
<body>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">AAA</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">BBB</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, if I add ng-include anywhere in the page, for example at the beginning of the page:

```
<body>
    <ng-include src="'page1.html'"></ng-include>
    ...
```

It doesn't matter what the included file contains, it can be even empty, but this will cause each click when switching tabs to add #/tab1, #/tab2, etc. to the page URL. This happens in all browsers, which is undesirable. On Chrome, this also causes the tab icon to flicker, and for a moment it shows default white icon before it reloads the page specific icon.

Anyone experienced something similar? Why adding ng-include would cause this?
I also tried doing the include without angular (by using jQuery.load()) and there is no issue seen.

This can be fully experienced on a standalone page, but on [this plnkr page](http://plnkr.co/edit/NHULQttHxclrxoQ1Eebh?p=preview) I created, although one cannot see the URL, and the flicker effect in Chrome is less visible, but still the effect can be seen in Chrome.

Comment: can u tell the exact url names

Comment: If the page is http://localhost/main.html the URLs would be http://localhost/main.html#/tab1 etc. This would be normal if no Javascript is activated to handle the clicks, since there are a href links with these URLs. However all Javascript files are loaded normally, and all works OK, until ng-include is added

Comment: can you setup a plunker.. you can print url using $location.path() & $location.hash()

Comment: @HarishR the plunker is already included in the post above, but it quite hard to see. http://plnkr.co/edit/NHULQttHxclrxoQ1Eebh?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The url changing behavior come from the `$location` service, which is used by `ng-include`. So you could be able to reproduce it by just injecting the `$location` service somewhere in your app.

See the **What does it do?** section of this [$location guide](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/docs/guide/$location), and the action that causing the problem is:

- Maintains synchronization between itself and the browser's URL when the user clicks on a link in the page

This answer your question "Why adding ng-include would cause this?".

To prevent the url from changing by the `$location` service, you could do it like this:

```
appModule.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function ($event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    // may add some logic here to prevent url changes only that come from clicking tab.
    $event.preventDefault();
  });
})
```

**Example plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/4289uwL1mHSRj6oP4dl1?p=preview

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, without ng-include, and with $location injected in one of the controllers, I could reproduce it as well.

Comment: So angular $location service is registering click event for all the links on the page! This can cause subtle undesired effects as the one above, combined with other library (in this case twitter bootstrap)

Comment: Ok, after doing some research, I found that this behavior can be prevented, please see the edited answer.